React jup terminal issue
useEffect(() => {
console.log("Initializing Jupiter...");
window.Jupiter.init({
  displayMode: "integrated",
  integratedTargetId: "integrated-terminal",
  endpoint: "https://rpc.ankr.com/solana",
  strictTokenList: false,
  defaultTokens: ["SOL", "RatSol"],
  formProps: {
    fixedInputMint: true,
    fixedOutputMint: true,
    swapMode: "ExactOut",
    fixedAmount: true,
    initialAmount: 1, 
    initialInputMint: "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112", 
    initialOutputMint: "HNRrr5YBYgBz3orDGVc4pGQsc5mnLtyVtfKaMt4WNDMz",  
  },
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Jupiter initialized successfully.");
}).catch(error => {
  console.error("Error initializing Jupiter:", error);
});

}, []);
I can balance my wallet, but it gives an error when I try to make a swap transaction even though there is a balance in my wallet. “Insufficient balance” is the error message. And at the bottom of the terminal I get the error “Your RPC is not responding to any requests.”, how can I fix it?
